# How can I include comments and show all code when printing out posts?

Tags: support, printing

I'm using the Firefox browser and trying to print out my posts (and replies). The PDF output doesn't include the comments in the posts. How to make sure that everything which is on the page gets printed? Same goes for codes for which are in a window. Only the visible part of the code gets printed.

These are not programming questions :) but I hope that someone can suggest how to get proper printouts of the posts.

Comment: Just double checked in Chrome and the "edit | close | flag" links are missing, but the comment does appear.

Comment: I didn't get the comments even with Chrome. The best solution for me at time is to copy everything in MS Word. You have everything then.

Comment: You might be interested in [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. StackPrinter is a much better solution. If you want, you can post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: done!

Comment: [A question from 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384268/print-view-content-only). It may be automatically deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look to [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com) app.
Using the [Stack Exchange Network API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) produces an essential printable view of a given question id with all the answers and all the comments.

Comment: Thanks. It works nicely. 1 vote up.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF printer takes a "snapshot" of the whole viewport, it does not take benefit of the CSS print stylesheet to make all the code and comments to overflow and visible.

This is rather a client side issue. You may peek around in your PDF print settings if there isn't an option to change the CSS used when printing to PDF. The only the stackexchange guys can do is to provide a link like "Download this question as PDF" and generate the whole PDF serverside the way as you would get with the CSS print style. As this is a pretty expensive job, I wouldn't expect much.

Comment: This shouldn't be true. A PDF *printer* should get the same information as any other printer. (Now, *saving* as PDF, like when using the PDF button in the Mac OS X print dialog is different. For OS X, when using Safari or OmniWeb, the resulting PDFs even contain clickable links -- whereas the very same button pressed from Firefox does not yield anything clickable.)

Comment: @Arjan: Hmm, it apparently depends on the PDF plugin used. I can reproduce exactly the same problem as the OP with the "PDF printer" option in Firefox. It's maybe because I've a complete Adobe pack installed at this machine or maybe yours does things differently. Using latest FF on Windows XP by the way. This is going to be more a question for superuser.

Comment: I'm sure one can reproduce it, but doesn't printing to a real printer give you the same results?

Comment: No, it truly uses the provided CSS print stylesheet instead.

Comment: Thanks all your comments. I haven't tried on a real printer yet. Yes I'm using the latest FF in Win XP and I have Acrobat 8.2. For now, I'm thinking just to copy the whole page and paste it to a word processor like MS Word. I don't see any setting for CSS when I print using Acrobat. I can give it a try with Chrome as one suggested here.

Comment: Copying everything into MS Word seems to be a working solution.